# DT package filters not showing set ranges/values in Markdown, but filtering works

Tags: markdown, dt

I have created an interactive table with the `DT` package in R, and added column filters. The filters work, and it is possible to set the ranges of values, or groups to be displayed, but the filter fields do not display the ranges or names. Only the multiple selection boxes for the factor variables work as intended.

```
datatable(DTdata, rownames = FALSE, filter = "top", colnames = str_replace_all(colnames(DTdata), "_", " "))
```

(I need the `str_replace_all` part for a better UX, because my variable names contain underscores, but it works the same way regardless)